# getting data from database in laravel using the username

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table in database called 'User'. All I want is to get the basic information of the user. I've tried to get data from database but the thing that keep me bugging is that I get all the data inside the  table.
`UserTable`

```
|id|username|firstname|lasttname|middlename|gender|age|birthdate|address|contact_number|designation|
 1   admin    lee       chiu      kim        male  47   07-22-87  cebu     0977452445    admin
 2   lrose    rose       loo      mar       female 27   04-02-88  cebu     0977452445    manager
 3   mgray    gray       men      try        male  37   01-22-89  cebu     0977452445    employee
```

`UserProfile.php` --> Model

```
<?php 
    class UserProfile  extends Eloquent   {
        public $timestamps=false;
        protected $table = 'users';
        protected $fillable=array('firstname','lastname', 'middlename', 'gender', 'age', 'birthdate', 'address', 'contact_number', 'designation');
    }
```

This is the model of my site.

`UserProfileContoller.php` --> Controller

```
<?php
class UserProfileController extends \BaseController {
    public function index($id)
    {
        $userprofile = User::find($id);

        return View::make('userprofile.index', array('userprofile' => $userprofile));

        //return View::make('userprofile.index')->with('UserProfiles',UserProfile::get());
    }
```

For example I am currently log in to username admin and I want to edit and view my profile. How can I get the data just for admin only. Please Help.

The situation hers is that. let say they have 3 employees. So in the table 3 username. lets assume that I'm not the admin. I will log in using lrose. and the other one log in as admin and so.on. If the three of us will go to our profiles the only thing to display there is their own profile and can edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you property set-up your database why not just use the `DB` object?

```
 // In the User table find the item with the username 'admin'
 DB::table('User')->where('username', '=', 'admin')->get();
```

To get the information of some user that is logged in (given you have their username), called something like `$userprofile`. Then all we need to do is `find` by id then get the `username`:

```
 // $id is the ID of the logged in user
 $userprofile = User::find($id)->username; // get username of logged in user
```

Comment: well it depends on who they are or in the other words depends on what username they. It the other user is not admin. How can they get their information ? just like taht

Comment: @akimebless I've added a way to do that. You had the right idea, you just need to do a `->username` to get the username of the logged in user.

Comment: I've tried it but I got this error `Missing argument 1 for UserProfileController::index()` The code is this `public function index($id)
 {
  $UserProfile = User::find($id)->username;
  return View::make('UserProfile.index')->with('UserProfile',UserProfile::get());
 }`

Comment: @akimebless It's `$UserProfile` not `UserProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

$userprofile::find($id) will get you the information for admin only, if $id = 1.

find() only returns 1 tuple from the database.

After you call find(), you can access the data as such:

```
$userprofile->firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean when you pass $id to index method of User Controller all the data of other users are returned?

That's kinda weird.

1. $userprofile = User::find($id); change that line to $userprofile = User::find(1); and see if you can only get the data of admin.
2. If not, probably you are calling other method. Probably you iterate over the index method somewhere else for multiple times so that you get all the data in the database. To confirm both possibilities, just add echo 'I am in' at the entry point of your index method. If no echo message is shown, the first possibility is true. If multiple echo messages occur, the second possibility is true.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to use `Session` after login and store the `id` of the username in the Session.

e.g.

**Step 1:**

```
if($login) //successfull login
{
    Session::put('userid', $userid);
    //this id, you have to retreive it from the database after successful login
}
```

**Step 2:**

Setup the `route`

```
Route::get('profile',['uses' => 'UserProfileContoller@index']);
```

**Step 3:**

*Controller*

```
public function index()
{
     if(is_null(Session::get('userid'))) return Redirect::to('login');

     return View::make('userprofile.index', ['userprofile' => $this->model->index()]);
     // Above code uses dependency injection to retrieve the information from db.
}
```

**Step 4:**

*UserProfileModel*

```
public function index()
{
    return DB::table('user')->where('id','=', Session::get('userid'))->first();
}
```

`p.s. i find it easier to use query builder than eloquent orm. if you want to use orm, change the code where needed.`

Comment: what should I put in view ?

Comment: put whatever info you are retrieving from the database. view can be anything.

Comment: okay I got your point. just to ask question what is `Creating default object from empty value`?

Comment: you haven't intialised the object but you are trying to assign value to it.